# Custom index for dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe:

```
   1/3/2011  4/1/2021  3/31/2021  ...  1/6/2011  1/5/2011  1/4/2011
0   0.424247  0.209943   0.209942  ...  0.494431  0.478675  0.442692
1   0.428014  0.210241   0.210241  ...  0.499361  0.484653  0.446848
2   1.127805  0.356723   0.362666  ...  1.332204  1.339620  1.178887
3   2.220437  0.913629   0.949701  ...  2.366291  1.942443  2.209880
4   3.213573  1.556866   1.624042  ...  3.312162  3.151239  3.213159
5   4.025311  2.030883   2.105356  ...  4.069105  4.866949  4.019084
6   4.555883  2.315257   2.397099  ...  4.601537  4.717146  4.527070
7   4.803622  2.447491   2.529781  ...  4.847289  4.939370  4.784244
8   4.982618  2.528838   2.605640  ...  5.006495  5.110961  4.936500
9   5.049444  2.548326   2.641850  ...  5.096861  5.214397  5.045123
10  5.183262  2.588166   2.668743  ...  5.207816  5.301237  5.166312
11  5.227674  2.624253   2.703215  ...  5.276020  5.367465  5.241496
12  5.247942  2.633068   2.716046  ...  5.318237  5.399149  5.286811
13  5.274951  2.615380   2.701839  ...  5.343966  5.393002  5.310892
14  5.267717  2.588757   2.676699  ...  5.332641  5.356331  5.299973
15  5.207645  2.557645   2.644474  ...  5.271866  5.287435  5.244266
16  5.097226  2.522334   2.605892  ...  5.163959  5.188291  5.145620
17  4.987161  2.486294   2.567273  ...  5.056751  5.091500  5.046471
18  4.893541  2.450168   2.530107  ...  4.965447  5.007443  4.959943
19  4.823184  2.414322   2.494957  ...  4.896898  4.942282  4.892097
20  4.782205  2.378828   2.462084  ...  4.857204  4.901275  4.848124
21  4.769757  2.344163   2.431462  ...  4.845584  4.883970  4.827838
22  4.754436  2.310346   2.400372  ...  4.830733  4.863281  4.805725
23  4.727185  2.277665   2.368254  ...  4.803574  4.831505  4.774819
24  4.684759  2.246143   2.334896  ...  4.760727  4.785601  4.732571
25  4.627248  2.216407   2.300755  ...  4.702254  4.726026  4.679888
26  4.562172  2.190393   2.268304  ...  4.635846  4.660460  4.624084
27  4.530679  2.175844   2.248211  ...  4.603836  4.629887  4.602763
28  4.550864  2.175709   2.244352  ...  4.624965  4.652757  4.633093
29  4.632196  2.191131   2.258115  ...  4.709154  4.739082  4.724527
30  4.787292  2.223629   2.291247  ...  4.869629  4.902260  4.889937
31  4.893589  2.246091   2.314864  ...  4.979662  5.013891  5.001563
```

I want to change the index such as the first one is 3M USD 0Y1Y, next one is 3M USD 1Y1Y, 3M USD 2Y1Y and so on, but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: What are these `3M USD 0Y1Y, 3M USD 1Y1Y,`? I don't see anything like this in your sample df.

Comment: Are you referring to the columns when you say the "index?" And could you please describe more on the logic behind the naming convention?

Comment: Sorry should've been more clear, the index of the example df is currently the first column so 0 -31. The logic behind the naming is that the data above are forward swap rates for 3M USD libor, so 0Y1Y would be starting at the date at the top, and then ending in 1 years time.

Comment: 1Y1Y  = a swap starting one year later from the date and lasting one year etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this really answers your question, but you should be able to do this with list comprehension

```
df.index = [f"3M USD {x}Y1Y" for x in range(len(df))]
```